# Efficient proof for Cartesian product

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments, verifiability

I am trying to find some efficient zero-knowledge arguments that could prove the vector ${\bf v}$ is the Cartesian product of two vectors ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$. I know there are efficient inner product arguments, but are there any efficient arguments for Cartesian products?

For example, given three (vector) commitments $com({\bf x})$, $com({\bf y})$, and $com({\bf v})$ to ${\bf x,y}$ and ${\bf v}$, respectively, how to prove the knowledge of the opening to the three commitments and ${\bf v}$ is the Cartesian product of ${\bf x,y}$.

Comment: You probably should spell out what you mean by "zk", and make it more clear how this is a crypto problem and not a math one.